# Where to test exit condition in while loop

Tags: while-loop, break

Can anyone think of any advantages to the form

```
while(1) {
    ...
    if( exit_condition ) break;
    ...
}
```

over

```
while( !exit_condition ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you decide you want to leave the loop early, the first allows you to avoid executing extra logic. I think in general, you'd use the first ( or a combination of the two ) for large loops and the second for small loops. Where `exit_condition` is evaluated at the bottom of the loop, in embedded programming it might be good to get into the habit of using the second ( but even then, that small performance consideration will be made obsolete by most decent compilers for popular embedded languages such as C )

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can not calculate the `exit_condition` before you enter the loop.
Because you would need some computations or values, calculated inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Advantage is you would enter into the loop at least once. Rest is up to you on what to do inside the loop.

And the disadvantage is, it is not allowed in Java.

Comment: "And the disadvantage is, it is not allowed in Java.", I mean Java's not tagged, it looks like it's just supposed to be pseudo code. It might be good to add the valid Java equivalent `while(true)` if you think it's relevant.